# Angularjs resolve promise on .run and pass to controllers

Tags: angularjs, authentication, promise

i have some troubles with a API-Side login and Angular.

**The Scenario:**

Api Response at GET api/auth/token and, if exists and open sesion, return token and user data, else return false. API Response at POST api/auth/login for credentials and, if ok, return token and user data.

The frontend need to load api/auth/token first, if the response is false, go to the login form, else, load the user data and the session token for using it in controllers.

**What have i done:**

Everything works well, but i can`t use userdata in controllers.

**The Source**

app.run

```
app.run(function (ApiService, $state, $location) {
    if($location.url() != '/login'){
        ApiService.token().then(function (data) {
            if (data.data.hasOwnProperty('user')) {
                ApiService.user = data.data.user;
                ApiService.token = data.data.token;
                ApiService.permissions = data.data.permissions;
                ApiService.auth = true;
            } else {
                $state.go('login');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

app.factory

```
app.factory('ApiService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var api = {
        'api': 'api/v1/',
        'auth': false,
        'request': null,
        'token': null,
        'user': null,
        'permissions': null
    };
    api.token = function () {
        return $http.get(api.api + 'auth/token').success(function () {
        });
    };
    api.logIn = function (credentials) {
        return $http.post(api.api + 'auth/try', credentials).success(function () {
        });
    };
    api.logOut = function () {
        return $http.get(api.api + 'auth/logout').success(function () {
        });
    };
    return api;
}]);
```

With that, in MainCtrl, using console.log(ApiService.user) i can see all the user data, but if i want to assign it to a $scope with $scope.user = ApiService.user, i dont see anything.

Comment: Since call to getting token is async you cannot be sure when the `user` data is available. `run` method just makes sure that the call happen after config stage. Your MainCtrl may be loading before token request is complete.

Comment: You can return a promise and resolve it in a controller.  It would be good if you could mock this up in a punker or fiddle.

Comment: Solved using ui-router Resolve, thanks Chadermani!

Comment: @CheycronBlaine If you have found a solution, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to resolve the $http promise before the routing. Using ui-router:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('m', {
            templateUrl: "tpl.mainApp.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl",
            resolve: {
                token: function (ApiService) {
                    if (!ApiService.isLoggedIn) {
                        return ApiService.token();
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

This way, promise is resolved and ApiService.data is populated before controller loads and i can use all the data.